# Objective-C: order of signalling of GCD semaphores

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I defined obj-C method:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)f {
    dispatch_block_t b = ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        //do something

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    };
    dispatch_async(a, b); //MUST be dispatched to global concurrent queue, 
                          //referenced by a
}
```

Let's suppose that `f` is called concurrently from 3 different threads **t1, t2, t3** in that order, i.e. emulating serial execution.
Is it correct to suggest that *dispatch_semaphore_signal()* will be signalling in the same order?

If not then how can I ensure that the function is called in serial manner considering the limitations?

Comment: Your code of course infinitely locks.. you call `dispatch_semaphore_wait` forever.. in the block.. Which means "do something" and any code after it will never execute until the semaphore gets signalled somewhere else..

Comment: @Brandon: no. the semaphore is initialized with a count of 1. The wait call will decrease it to 0. And the signal call increases it to 1 again. That's fine.

Comment: BorisV, this semaphore pattern (and Michael’s locking pattern) are dangerous, notably if the “do something” code might takes any considerable time and if the number of threads you might call this from could be large. The issue is that this blocks GCD worker threads, which are quite limited (currently only 64 of them), at which point apps can hang and/or other unexpected behaviors. The serial queue pattern really is the right way to do this.

Comment: I see. However, my concern is different. I plan to create many objects, each one will deploy indefinite number of tasks on global concurrent queue. My concern is that if I provide each object with its own serial queue then it will cause massive impact on OS resources. On the other side if I define one shared serial queue then this will break order of deployment which is unwanted. So I try to figure out the best strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the semaphore like a basic concurrency lock. This means that your code is equivalent to

```
- (id)init{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        lock = [NSLock new];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)f{
    dispatch_block_t b= ^{
        [lock lock];

        //do something

        [lock unlock];
    };
    dispatch_async(a, b); //MUST be dispatched to global concurrent queue, 
                           //referenced by a
}
```

For this use case you usually use serial dispatch queues. Because it is much easier this way.

```
- (id)init{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)f{
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // do something
    });
}
```

However, back to your question. The blocks will usually be called in the same order that you schedule them, but only until there is load and it really matters. The only guarantee is that the code in `// do something` will not be executed concurrently.

GCD guarantees that blocks are starting to execute in the same order that they were scheduled. This is even true for concurrent queues. To see why this doesn't mean that `// do something` is called in the appropriate order, consider this:

```
Thread 1 schedules t1
Thread 2 schedules t2
t1 starts executing
t2 starts executing
t1 gets suspended because of high CPU load
t2 runs dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
Thread 3 schedules t3
t2 succeeds and starts with `// do something`
t1 gets unsuspended and calls dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
t1 now blocks
...
```

In this scenario (which will happen some day), t1 begins executing before t2, but still the `// do something` block from t2 gets executed first. *Depending on your use case, this may or may not be a problem for you.* If you need total ordering, you need to use a serial dispatch queue (recommended) or create your own locking scheme (not recommended unless you really need to.)

Comment: will the queue created with dispatch_queue_create_with_target(@"xyz",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL,DISPATCH_TARGET_QUEUE_DEFAULT) fulfill my requirements?

Comment: @BorisV: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. Why not create an ordinary serial dispatch queue with `dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)`?

Comment: I want to emulate serial execution of same function upon concurrent queue. Which means: in case when several threads access that function I want to start execution of next task right after previous was ended.

Comment: @BorisV: what is "upon concurrent queue"? Wether you use `dispatch_queue_create_with_target(@"xyz",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL,DISPATCH_TARGET_QUEUE_DEFAULT)` or `dispatch_queue_create("xyz", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)` will not change the observable behaviour of your program at all.